# Successfully solved a problem after I posted a question

Tags: discussion

I recently posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390866/fraction-of-original-velocity-in-series-of-elastic-collisions), which details I problem I had tried to solve for a while. Eventually I got fed up of trying to solve it and came here for help. However, soon after posting the question I realized how I could solve the question. I spent a while working it out and successfully solved the problem myself. I then looked up at my computer screen and saw that 2 answers had been posted to my question, which answered it accurately. Now I have a problem. What do I do? I don't want to delete the question (because people have put effort into answering it) but at the same time I solved the problem myself without their help. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: I would like to point out that math.se, and stackexchange in general, is  a repository of questions and answers, they are meant to help other people, not just yourself. So even if you had no answers on your question the "right" thing to do would be to add your answer, and not delete the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Post your own answer, and accept one of the two posted (preferably, the one which is more helpful to you, in general, whatever that might be).

This way other people who might run into this question will have the benefit of *three* answers and not just zero.

Comment: I'll accept the most helpful answer but I'm reluctant to supply my own because I solved it by exactly the same method as Harish Chandra Rajpoot, so an answer that I provide would be a duplicate of his

Comment: I'd write an answer, before posting it, let it sit for 30 minutes or so, then read your answer and compare it to the one Harish Chandra Rajpoot has given. If the answers are really the same, just add a comment under Harish's answer saying that this is how you managed to solve this on your own. if you present the solution in a slightly different way, or put a different emphasis on different things, then it's worth giving anyway since it might complement Harish's answer to some readers in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: @imulsion, then add a comment to the "duplicate" answer thanking for it, and explaining you independently got the same solution.